# Removing duplicates from a .txt file and creating a new .txt file

Tags: python, file

I have a .txt filled with data that I want to filter (approx. 5800 lines), since some lines occur as duplicates with the only difference that the timestamp is exactly 2 hours later. Those lines that are the late version of the duplicate (so for example the first line in the attached example) should be left out. All other lines should be left in and written to a new .txt file.

```
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 16:11:56 00:00:40    2   Sensor Check   #   should go
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 14:12:40 00:00:33    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 14:11:56 00:00:40    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 16:12:40 00:00:33    2   Sensor Check   #   should go
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 17:23:25 00:00:20    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 19:23:25 00:00:20    2   Sensor Check   #   should go
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 19:15:24 00:02:21    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 19:25:13 00:02:13    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
```

I wrote some code in Python, output is a .txt file with only 1 line of text:

```
deleted
```

I can't seem to solve this one. Can you help? See code below.

```
import os

def filter_file():
    with open("output.txt", "w") as output: 
        #open the input file from a specified directory
        directory = os.path.normpath("C:/Users/sande_000/Documents/Python files")
        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
            for file in files:
                if file.startswith("input"):
                    input_file=open(os.path.join(subdir, file))
                    #iterate over each line of the file
                    for line in input_file:
                        machine = line[0:7]             #stores machine number
                        date = line[8:18]               #stores date stamp
                        time_1 = int(line[19:21])       #stores hour stamp
                        time_2 = int(line[22:24])       #stores minutes stamp
                        time_3 = int(line[25:27])       #stores second stamp
                        #check current line with other lines for duplicates by iterating over each line of the file
                        for otherline in input_file:
                            compare_machine = otherline[0:7]            
                            compare_date = otherline[8:18]
                            compare_time_1 = int(otherline[19:21])+2
                            compare_time_2 = int(otherline[22:24])
                            compare_time_3 = int(otherline[25:27])
                            #check whether machine number & date/hour+2/minutes/seconds stamp are similar.
                            #If yes, write 'deleted' to output.txt and stop comparing lines.
                            #If no, continue with comparing next line.
                            if compare_machine == machine and compare_date == date and compare_time_1 == time_1 and compare_time_2 == time_2 and compare_time_3 == time_3:
                                output.write("deleted"+"\n")
                                break
                            else:
                                continue
                            #If no overlap between one line with any other line from the file, write that line to output.txt since it is no duplicate.
                            output.write(line)

                    input_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filter_file()
```

Comment: Surely `14:12:40` should stay and `16:12:40` should go, right? You have it the other way around.

Comment: there's no logic in your text file. Once the earlier should go, and for the other the earlier should stay. Also, your log file isn't sorted by date. Does order matter?

Comment: That was indeed a mistake, the text file should be logical now. For all clarity: the earlier should stay and the later should go. It's true that the log file isn't sorted by date, I cannot do anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code below works. Note that this code won't work if there's any variation in the smallest three time components of the records (milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds) on account of the fact that `datetime` doesn't support resolution beyond microseconds. In your example, that won't make a difference though.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

INPUT_DIR = 'C:\Temp'
OUTPUT_FILE = 'output.txt'


def parse_data(data):
    for line in data.splitlines():
        date_s = ' '.join(line.split()[1:3])
        date = datetime.strptime(date_s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        yield line, date


def filter_duplicates(data):
    duplicate_offset = timedelta(hours=2)

    parsed_data = list(parse_data(data))
    lines, dates = zip(*parsed_data)

    for line, date in parsed_data:
        if (date - duplicate_offset) not in dates:
            yield line


def get_input_data_from_dir(directory):
    data = ''
    for sub_dir, _, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.startswith('input'):
                with open(os.path.join(sub_dir, file)) as f:
                    data += f.read() + '\n'

    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = get_input_data_from_dir(INPUT_DIR)
    with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w') as f_out:
        content = '\n'.join(filter_duplicates(data))
        f_out.write(content)
```

Tested for input directory with structure:

```
me@my-computer /cygdrive/c/Temp
$ tree
.
├── input_1.txt
└── input_2.txt
```

`input_1.txt`:

```
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 16:11:56 00:00:40    2   Sensor Check
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 14:12:40 00:00:33    2   Sensor Check
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 14:11:56 00:00:40    2   Sensor Check
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 16:12:40 00:00:33    2   Sensor Check
```

`input_2.txt`:

```
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 17:23:25 00:00:20    2   Sensor Check
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 19:23:25 00:00:20    2   Sensor Check
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 19:15:24 00:02:21    2   Sensor Check
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 19:25:13 00:02:13    2   Sensor Check
```

`output.txt` after execution:

```
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 14:12:40 00:00:33    2   Sensor Check
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 14:11:56 00:00:40    2   Sensor Check
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 17:23:25 00:00:20    2   Sensor Check
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 19:15:24 00:02:21    2   Sensor Check
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 19:25:13 00:02:13    2   Sensor Check
```

Your expected output below, copied for convenience:

```
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 16:11:56 00:00:40    2   Sensor Check   #   should go
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 14:12:40 00:00:33    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 14:11:56 00:00:40    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
1_3_IMM 2016-07-19 16:12:40 00:00:33    2   Sensor Check   #   should go
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 17:23:25 00:00:20    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 19:23:25 00:00:20    2   Sensor Check   #   should go
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 19:15:24 00:02:21    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
1_4_IMM 2016-07-19 19:25:13 00:02:13    2   Sensor Check   #   should stay
```

Comment: I was writing almost the same python code and was at 80% when I saw your post. Upvoted. One issue though: the author asked for writing "delete" when seeing a duplicate

Comment: @hansaplast "the author asked for writing "delete" when seeing a duplicate" Where did you see that? OP wrote *"Those lines that are the late version of the duplicate (so for example the first line in the attached example) should be left out."*

Comment: @hansaplast Oh I see, I looked at the question body but not at the comments in his code. I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: great code, one thing: this prints the output, but I'd like to have the output written into a new output.txt file

Comment: @tagc yes, you are right, I was mistaken. It was in the code so I assumed this was wished behavior

Comment: and it's actually fine to have the words 'deleted' omitted from the output. I initially worked that way just to have more clarity on when my program would delete something or not

Comment: @Sander Is this okay?

Comment: Data is successfully transfered to an output.txt file. However, I currently have 5800+ lines of data now. Would be nice if the program would take its data from an input.txt file in a specified directory (see my initial code).

Comment: @Sander Phew. I think this does what you want. I'm going to have to leave the office soon anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think this shorter code should do it.
Is has two consecutive loops instead of nested loops which should increase performance.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# os.walk etc.

for file in files:
    if not file.startswith("input"):
        continue

    entries = set()

    # build up entries
    for line in input_file:
        machine = line[0:7]             #stores machine number
        date = datetime.strptime(line[8:27], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        entries.add((machine, date))

    #check entries
    for line in input_file:
        machine = line[0:7]             #stores machine number
        date = datetime.strptime(line[8:27], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - timedelta(hours=2)

        if (machine, date) in entries:
            output.write("deleted\n")
        else:
            output.write(line)
        output.flush()
```

Comment: Tried it several times and looks clean to me, but it fails to write anything to output.txt. Just an empty file...

Comment: You might need to call output.flush() after writing.

Comment: Unfortunately, no effect

Comment: This code has an issue when the two hours cross midnight. You should use datetime and timedelta to compare

Comment: @hansaplast You are right. I added that (and also the `.flush()`).

Comment: @Sander Strange. Does printing work? - (BTW if you check on `not file .startswith("input")` you can save one level of indention.)